# Want to download an unsupported app, but says it will replace an app

Tags: applications

What does it mean when it says it will replace an app?

Answer (score 3):

It means that an app with the same app id is already installed in your phone.

For eg: If there is an app with id com.example.app and you try to install another apk with same ID it will give that message.